# How can i get a checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a checkbox and I fails to check the status (full or empty).    I want to send a mail if the checkbox is full.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)" />
```

```
function checkAddress(checkbox)
  {
    if (checkbox.checked == true)
    {
        status==1;
    }
  }


function secSendMailFunction(){
 for(var i=1; i<4; i++){
  if(status==i){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
    mail=snapshot.child(i).child("Mail").val();
   })
  }
 }
```

Comment: what is  status==1; in first function notice double equal to(==).

Comment: First of all, `status==1` is wrong, I am assuming that you want `status` to have a value of 1, so use `=` instead. Then, how exactly will the checkbox becomes full?

Comment: Where you define status in code? in checkAddress function replace == to = for status variable

Comment: It would be better to check the checkboxes `checked` property directly rather than abstracting it through a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are doing wrong assignment -

`status==1;` this is not correct, `==` / `===` is an conditional statement. You want to assign a value to `status` not compare it. Use `=`

I suggest you to choose `onchange` instead `onclick`. `Checkbox` is a type of input which possibly have only two values either `true`/ `false`. Triggering event will be good in this case

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.onchange = function(el) {
  if(el.srcElement.checked){
    alert('do my job')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```